# Mask mobile number in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a mobile number that format like "+90-111-222-3333333"
I create a method includes regex for masking last part of number. (in example 3333333)
How can I replace part that after last - character of this number in any other way?
Here is my code;

```
private String maskedMsisdn(String msisdn)
{
    String regex =   "^\\(?(\\+\\d{2})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{7})$";
    boolean isValid = msisdn.matches(regex);
    if(isValid)
    {
        return msisdn.replaceAll(regex, "$1-$2-*******");
    }
    return "";
}
```

I dont want to put ****** character in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Don't most places mask everything except the final three digits of the phone number?

Comment: `replaceAll("\\d(?!.*-)(?=\\d|$)", "*")` will work for you

Comment: @TheLostMind this answer exactly that I want. Thanks